# Installing latest stable kernel (3.3.1) in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, kernel

Good evening everyone. Sorry if this question already have being answered but I used ALL my Search power.
For example I want to install latest kernel (which is 3.3.1 right now according to http://kernel.org/). I go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/  find kernel 3.3.1 but I run Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot not Precise so the question is can I install kernel 3.3.1 without paying attention to the precise name near it or should I build my own kerel from kernel.org ?
thank you for your answer.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to upgrade the kernel? Are you trying to solve an issue?

Comment: No, only training and studying purposes. I am using my old one computer so I am not afraid of breaking something.

Comment: However there is a reason for me to try out latest kernel on my new computer as well. As i read in kernel changelog there is an improvement in EUFI boot. I want to test it.

Comment: Download the corresponding debs, install them. done. Running 3.3 in 11.10 now.

Comment: I am currently running 3.2.4 in Natty. Download the .debs from the repository and install.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/03/upgrade-to-kernel-33-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: yes I saw that but my question was can I upgrade my kernel to 3.3.1 even thou I am running Ubuntu 11.10 not Precise ?

Comment: Yes you can upgrade-

Comment: People I upgraded my kernel and it went perfect, but at start before LightDM log in start I receive this error ERROR MUX INFO CALL FAILED. What does it mean ? I googled but didn't understand, system anyway boot up normally.

Comment: @NikitaKononov Ignore that, you have an intel graphics card with possibly a dedicated video card. Newer models do not have the mux for integrated/discrete video card so you can ignore that.

Comment: Yes I do Have Intel HD graphics 3000 + Nvidia GT 540M Optimus =) thank you for answering my question =) really appreciate that.